# Fastest way to import CSV into Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, csv

I am using Postgres and I want to import some data from a CSV into my database. However the data is "relational" so I can't just do a row by row import.

For example I have a `Category` table. A row can include multiple categories in the format `Comedy;Crime;Drama` so I need to find the correct category from `Category` so I can create a relation. Edit: the `Category` table is already pre-populated with unique values.

What is a fast way to do this? I expect to parse 60-80GB but possible more in the future so I want something fast.

I tried to do this quickly with Node where I would stream the file, find and create the relations for each line. The pool could not handle this so I have to read, pause, process, resume, repeat.

I'm using a quad-core i7 so I also feel like I could easily speed this process now that Node is single-threaded. How should I approach this?

Comment: Typically you would import the "raw" CSV file into a staging table, then insert from there using SQL probably using `unnest(string_to_array(...))` to generate multiple rows from the delimited values

Comment: I made a small edit: the `Category` table will already be pre-populated with values. `Comedy` for example would just have to find the correct `id` to create the relation. I had thought about importing the CSV into a temporary table but I am not sure how to go about doing that.